# EVP_EncryptFinal_ex returns error when no plaintext is provided

Tags: c++11, encryption, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I used the EVP functions that provides a high level interface to OpenSSL cryptographic functions to write a library that performs encryption and decryption operations. This library uses **EVP_aes_128_gcm** for encryption and decryption purposes.

I was able to provide the **Key, IV, AAD, Plain Text** and get the **cipher text, tag** successfully.

However, the problem comes when I just want to authenticate the AAD but doesn't want any encryption. So I took the below test cases from [NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/gcmtestvectors.zip)

*Key = 77be63708971c4e240d1cb79e8d77feb

IV = e0e00f19fed7ba0136a797f3

AAD = 7a43ec1d9c0a5a78a0b16533a6213cab

Tag = 209fcc8d3675ed938e9c7166709dd946

PT =

CT =*

Now I am getting the return value on **EVP_EncryptFinal_ex** API as **0** which is an error atleast as per the documentation:

> EVP_EncryptInit_ex(), EVP_EncryptUpdate() and EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()
> return 1 for success and 0 for failure.

However, when I tried to print the error, I don't get any error:

*EVP_EncryptFinal_ex failed - OpenSSL error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)*

```
int ret    = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf + outlen, &outlen);
if (ret <= 0)
{
    printf("EVP_EncryptFinal_ex failed - OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
    return -1;
}
```

One more interesting point is that if I don't check the return code and get the tag afterwards, I am getting correct tag as **209fcc8d3675ed938e9c7166709dd946**

```
if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_GET_TAG, 16, tag)) {
    printf("EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl: failed\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Also, I am using AES-GCM, so there is no padding. So the below statement is not valid for this scenario:

> If padding is disabled then EVP_EncryptFinal_ex() will not encrypt any
> more data and it will return an error if any data remains in a partial
> block: that is if the total data length is not a multiple of the block
> size.

Any ideas where I can be doing wrong?

Comment: Better tags for you

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem for your test vector, i.e. `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` returns `1` on my machine. Please post your code. Which OpenSSL version are you using?

Comment: @Topaco Actually I figured it out. I was calling EVP_EncryptUpdate on the empty plain text before calling EVP_EncryptFinal_ex. If you are expecting only the signing of the AAD but no encryption is involved, then you don't need to call it. Removing this API actually solved the issue. Anyhow thanks for your support.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. For me it works with and without the `EVP_EncryptUpdate()` call on the empty plaintext, but that may be implementation details.

Comment: @Topaco  Actually when I implemeted in plain c like sequential statments it was working fine. However, what is have a c++ template style class with functions such as init, update, final and these functions being called by the user sequentially. When I use such generic template style, I got the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I calling the **EVP_EncryptUpdate** on an empty plaintext after AAD sometimes causes the problems. However, removing the API **EVP_EncryptUpdate** on empty plain text resolves the problem.

You can find the complete code sample below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <vector>

int main()
{
    constexpr int TAG_LENGTH = 16;
    const std::vector<uint8_t> key{0x77,0xbe,0x63,0x70,0x89,0x71,0xc4,0xe2,0x40,0xd1,0xcb,0x79,0xe8,0xd7,0x7f,0xeb};
    const std::vector<uint8_t> iv{0xe0,0xe0,0x0f,0x19,0xfe,0xd7,0xba,0x01,0x36,0xa7,0x97,0xf3};
    const std::vector<uint8_t> aad{0x7a,0x43,0xec,0x1d,0x9c,0x0a,0x5a,0x78,0xa0,0xb1,0x65,0x33,0xa6,0x21,0x3c,0xab};
    const std::vector<uint8_t> expected_tag{0x20,0x9f,0xcc,0x8d,0x36,0x75,0xed,0x93,0x8e,0x9c,0x71,0x66,0x70,0x9d,0xd9,0x46};

    std::vector<uint8_t> actualtag;
    actualtag.resize(TAG_LENGTH);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == nullptr) 
    {
        printf("EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_gcm(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)) 
    {
        printf("EVP_EncryptInit_ex: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_IVLEN, iv.size(), nullptr)) 
    {
        printf("EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, key.data(), iv.data())) 
    {
        printf("EVP_EncryptInit_ex: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));                
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int length = 0;
    if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, nullptr, &length, aad.data(), aad.size())) 
    {
        printf("EVP_EncryptUpdate: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));                
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, nullptr, &length)) 
    {
        printf("EVP_EncryptFinal_ex: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Get tag */
    if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_GET_TAG, TAG_LENGTH, actualtag.data())) 
    {
        printf("EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl: OpenSSL error: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    printf("Actual Tag: ");
    for (auto i: actualtag)
        printf("%02hhx", i);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Expected Tag: ");
    for (auto i: expected_tag)
        printf("%02hhx", i);
    printf("\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You see, faster here.